# Closed form of $\sum_{r=1}^a\frac{1}{r(n-r)}$, where $a<n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, summation-method

I am trying to find a closed form for the following summation, where $a<n$, and $n$ is a fixed constant:
$$\sum_{r=1}^a\frac{1}{r(n-r)}$$
Do you have any ideas about how I'd go about doing this? Formulae for specific values of $n$, as well as any hints, would also be very helpful. Unfortunately I can't show any working or my attempts as I simply don't have any idea about how I'd proceed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\frac 1 {r(n-r)}=\frac  1 n (\frac 1 r +\frac  1{n-r})$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I noticed that. How does that help though?

Comment: This gives you a closed form in terms of [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), and there's *nothing more* to expect.

Comment: @metamorphy has it been conclusively proved there's no closed form for the harmonic series?